# Could I use Green's Theorem here?

Tags: integration, greens-theorem

I want to solve for the line integral:

$$\tag{1}\oint \alpha\nabla \phi_i\cdot \hat{\textbf{n}} ds$$

on the square boundary: $(0\le x \le 1, 0), (1,0 \le y \le 1), (1 \le x \le 0, 1),(0,1\le y \le 0)$

Where the function $\phi_i = \sin(n\pi x)\sin(n\pi y)$ and $\alpha = 1$ on the boundary. I don't know how $\hat{\textbf{n}}$ is oriented with respect to the gradient of $\phi_i$, so would it be possible to instead use Green's theorem $\oint_C Pdx + Qdy = \int\int_D \Big(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\Big) dA$ and compute the double integral instead?

Comment: Green's theorem would be a very good idea. You'll find that the integral is equal to $0$.

Comment: @Volk what if $\alpha$ is not constant inside the square?

Comment: @KurtG. Ah, right... I misread the problem and thought that $\alpha=1$ applied to the entire region. That's certainly less trivial although I think Green's theorem still holds because on the boundary we have $\alpha$ being a constant which means that we have;

$$\oint\alpha\nabla\phi_{i}\cdot d\bf{S}=\alpha\bigg[\oint\nabla\phi_{i}\cdot d\bf{S}\bigg]$$

and we can then apply Green's theorem to the integral normally. Unless I'm being an idiot (very possible) I think that we still have the integral being equal to $0$.

Comment: @Volk No no. Unless I am an idiot the following is true: The generalized Stokes theorem is, as we know, $$
\textstyle\int_{\partial\,\Omega}\omega=\int_{\Omega}d\omega\,.
$$ If $\alpha$ is an arbitrary function that is one on the boundary then

$$
\textstyle\int_{\partial\,\Omega}\omega=\int_{\partial\,\Omega}\alpha\,\omega=\int_{\Omega}d(\alpha\,\omega)=\int_\Omega\,d\alpha\wedge\omega+\int_\Omega\alpha\,d\omega\,.
$$
In particular the middle integral and the RHS are independent of $\alpha\,.$ Then what you told OP is totally correct.

Comment: I just verified this for the case $$
\alpha(x,y)=x^2+y^2\,,\quad \omega=-y\,dx+x\,dy\,,
$$ on the unit disk.

Comment: @Volk well yes it would be 1 on the boundary, I believe you had it correct. I was afraid it would be 0, since this integral arose when finding the inhomogeneous part of the solution to some PDE, and $\alpha$ is the value of the solution on the boundary. This integral should not equate to 0, unless the boundary conditions are homogenous i.e. $\alpha = 0$ on the boundary. So if it evaluates to 0, then something has gone wrong. I believe I also obtained 0 when performing the line integration which had me confused, so I wanted to see if I could verify the result instead using the double integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient of
$$
\phi(x,y) = \sin(n\pi x)\sin(n\pi y)
$$
is
$$
\nabla\phi=n\pi\pmatrix{\cos(n\pi x)\sin(n\pi y)\\\sin(n\pi x)\cos(n\pi y)}\,.
$$
The divergence of that gradient is
$$
\Delta\phi(x,y)=-2\,n^2\pi^2\sin(n\pi x)\sin(n\pi y)\,.
$$
By Gauss' and Green's theorem
\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial\,Q}\nabla\phi\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,ds
=\int_Q\Delta\phi\,dA
\end{align}
where $Q$ is your square and $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ the outward pointing unit normal
at the boundary.

It should be very easy to calculate the $dA$ integral over the square. If it is zero
or not depends on whether $n$ is odd or even.

Since the function $\alpha$ is one on the boundary it has no influence on these results.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a shot and see what my result is. It should be nonzero based on the context that this integral arises from. This line integral I showed is relating to the inhomogeneous boundary conditions of the solution to some PDE (Poisson) where $\alpha$ is the definition of the solution on the boundary. This integral should only evaluate to 0 in the case that $\alpha$ is 0 (i.e. the boundary conditions are homogeneous) according the textbook I was this reading from.

Comment: I picked $\alpha = 1$ completely arbitrarily. I suppose a more realistic case would be having $\alpha$ be different for each side of the square. I hope it can still be calculated regardless.

Comment: It's too long to show my workings in a comment, so I provided my worked out answer. Does this look about right?

Answer (score 0):

So going off of Kurt G, for $\alpha = 1$ on the boundaries, I should get:

$$\oint_C 1\nabla \phi_i \cdot \hat{\textbf{n}} ds = \int\int_D \nabla \cdot \nabla\phi_i dA$$

And computing the double integral, I should get:

$$-2(n\pi)^2\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sin(n\pi x)\sin(n \pi y)dxdy = \\ 2n\pi \int_0^1 \Big(\cos(n\pi x)|_0^1\Big)\sin(n\pi y)dy = \\ 2n\pi \Big((-1)^n -1\Big)\int_0^1 \sin(n\pi y)dy = \\ -2\Big((-1)^n -1\Big)\Big(\cos(n\pi y)|_0^1\Big) = \\ \boxed{-2\Big((-1)^n -1\Big)^2}$$

Is that correct?

---

EDIT:

Plugging this result into $$b_i = \int\int f(x,y) \phi(x,y)_i dA +\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_i \cdot \hat{\textbf{n}}ds$$ to obtain the solution $$u(x,y) = \sum_i b_i\phi_i$$, yielded a solution about 99.3% accurate compared to the desired solution within the domain. This can be seen by comparing the 2 plots below.

[image]

The problem with the plot on the left which I intentionally excluded the values of the solution on the boundary, also evaluated to 0 meaning this solution for whatever reason maintained its homogeneity when it was supposed to be inhomogeneous with the values of the solution being 1. Not sure why this happened.

Comment: Looks right. $\phantom{.}$

Comment: @KurtG. I tried using this and something isn't quite right. I don't know if it was this result, or I made a mistake applying this result. I might need to make a separate post showing what happened.

Comment: @KurtG. Oh and I made a mistake, it's actually $\phi_i = \sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)$, so our integrand should be $$-\pi^2\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)(n^2+m^2)$$. Unless I made a mistake, the result would actually be $$\frac{((-1)^n-1)((-1)^m-1)(n^2+m^2)}{nm}$$

Comment: @KurtG. nevermind. I think it actually did work to some extent, I was coding in a CAS and screwed up the summation. I've since corrected the mistake, and this result for the line integral leads to a fairly accurate result for the solution I was using it to obtain. I have posted a plot in my answer so that you can see the plots verifying this result. Sorry if my previous message worried you! Cheers!